# Is it possible to see the state of a multi index table for a given block number?

Tags: cleos, multi-index, blocks

Does the ability currently exist in EOS to see how the state of a persistent memory table was at some point in the past?

Answer (score 1):

In a full node, only current state of persistent memory is available. If you want to checkout a history state, you can try to use demux(https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js) to replay the chain and get the state you desire at given block.